# Как спрятать overflow на странице, но при этом сохранить возможность её скролить?

Tags: css

На странице нужно скрыть ползунок скрола. Пользуюсь параметром `overflow:hidden;`

Скролл скрывается, но при этом пропадает возможность скроллить страницу.

Как убрать ползунок скрола, но оставить возможность скролить страницу?

Answer (score 2):

Позиционируйте блок с контентом абсолютно и смещайте на расстояние ползунка.

Пример:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    position: absolute; right: -30px;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Т.к., думаю, нужен именно вертикальный скрол, то лучше у контета сделать `overflow-y: scroll;` А в целом, самый правильный способ